# Difference between onManagedUpdate method and touchevent handling?

Tags: android, andengine, touch-event

While working with and-engine I came across two different ways of doing a particular event handling i.e. ***OnManagedUpdate*** and touchEvents of ***onActionDown***, ***onActionUp***, and ***onActionMove***. I want to know, which method is to be used under what circumstances, given that accuracy and efficiency are not the trade-offs that are to be compromised. Secondly, what is the exact working of ***OnManagedUpdate*** method and how does it function? I am new to And gaming engine for android, any beginners explanation would be of great help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

onManagedUpdate is called every time an entity is updated , touch event handling should happen in the onSceneTouchEvent as it gets triggered only when the scene gets a touch event while onManagedUpdate is called about 60 times per second [depending on the frame rate] so if you want to do something every frame [render,check condition] do it there

there is also the onUpdate() method which does basically the same thing

http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/different-between-onmanagedupdate-and-onupdate-t8486.html?sid=52dd7f54cd341ac8ad100adab9fc5513